# How streaming process deals with historical aggregation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, spark-streaming

I have a query to sum up all users' historical cost, like

```
select uid, sum(payments) from tb
```

The table `tb` comprises 2 years' data - assume if you run it now, the query calculates 2 years' data while if you run it 1 year later, it will involves 3 years' data...

Is it possible to do this historical sum up streamingly? What is the standard method?

In addition...If the query is too complicated to rewrite, is it possible to apply streaming process on this query without any 'middle' result?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From a Flink perspective, there's nothing wrong with that query. In a streaming mode, it will run indefinitely and will just create a changelog stream as output. You can find more details on this on the [Continuous Queries](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/concepts/dynamic_tables/#continuous-queries) section of Flink's Dynamic Tables.